# Upload directly to S3 from django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, amazon-s3

I'm really stuck here.

I want to be able to upload directly to S3 from a django form.
This is going to be used to hold display pictures.

I followed this: http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

but unfortunately I get stuck at adding

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3.S3Storage'
```

to settings.py for some reason. django doesn't even recognize the change that i have made. (I changed it to DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'asdsfsdfsdf' and it didn't even give an error.
The funny thing is that I don't even know if django-storages has the feature i'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have a script at that location? It wouldn't give an error until it tried to execute. If you do have such a script, could you post more of the code?

Comment: Just ran into this exact issue -- did you ever figure this out?

Comment: As did I, using the same django-storages app he was. The instructions he links to shows the settings, and then directs one to use the django shell to see the changes in effect. However, nothing changes and django reports the regular default file storage. If I resolve it, I'll update here.

Comment: This answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108186/custom-default-file-storage-in-django

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](https://github.com/yaniv-aknin/django-s3upload) a working example I once wrote, `django-s3upload`.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't too difficult. The steps are to generate a policy document, sign it, and then use that signature to POST the file to S3. I wrote a little application called sbit3 that does this. Take a look here: https://github.com/victortrac/sbit3/blob/master/server/sbit3.py, specifically the PostHandler class:

```
class PostHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def _generate_policy_doc(self, conditions, expiration=None):
        if not expiration:
            # Sets a policy of 15 minutes to upload file
            expiration = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
        conditions = [ { "bucket" : conditions["bucket"] },
                       [ "starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"],
                       { "acl" : conditions["acl"] },
                       { "success_action_redirect" : conditions["success_action_redirect"] } ]
        conditions_json = json.dumps({ "expiration" : expiration.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"),
                                       "conditions" : conditions })
        logging.debug("Policy doc generated: {0}".format(conditions_json))
        return base64.b64encode(conditions_json)

    def _sign_policy(self, policy):
        signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(settings.aws_secret_key, policy, hashlib.sha1).digest())
        return signature

    def get(self, expiration):
        try:
            expiration = int(expiration)
            # Set max expiration to 7200 minutes (5 days)
            if not 0 < expiration < 7200:
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(403)
            _expireTimestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=expiration)
        except ValueError:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(403)

        # Associate _uuid to expiration in sdb

        _uuid = uuid.uuid4().hex
        sdb_conn.add_item(_uuid, expireTimestamp=_expireTimestamp)

        conditions = { "bucket" : settings.bucket,
                       "acl" : settings.acl,
                       "success_action_redirect" : settings.site_url + "/f/" + _uuid }
        policy_document = self._generate_policy_doc(conditions)
        signature = self._sign_policy(policy_document)

        self.render("post.html", conditions=conditions,
                                 aws_access_id=settings.aws_access_id,
                                 policy_document=policy_document,
                                 signature=signature)
```

The look at the [post.html](https://github.com/victortrac/sbit3/blob/master/server/post.html) that sets up the form:

```
<form action="https://{{ conditions["bucket"] }}.s3.amazonaws.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}">
  <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="{{ aws_access_id }}"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="{{ conditions["acl"] }}"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="{{ conditions["success_action_redirect"] }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="{{ policy_document }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="{{ signature }}">

  File to upload to S3: 
  <input name="file" type="file"> 
  <br> 
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to upload directly to S3(bypassing your webserver) you will need to directly post through the browser to a pre-authorized url.  Read [this article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) from amazon that explains how it needs to work.

I don't know of anything that will do this for you in django, but it is not too difficult to make the request yourself.  You can also use something like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to do the actual posting from the browser, you just need to give it the right url.